# how to remove the commas from a strings that contains commas in a list (Python)

Tags: python

This is just one line of a file that reads a list of numbers.

I need to remove the commas in the numbers.
These numbers are already strings.
I am having trouble figuring out how to write this.

['0', '0', '0', '0', '1,799', '']

how would i change 1,799 to 1799

i tried this

```
        for i in str(doses):
            if "," in i:
                i.replace(",", "")
```

but it didn't do anything

plz help me understand what i did wrong.

Comment: `replace()` does not change the original string, it makes a new one, so you need to do something with the new string like `new_string = old_string.replace(',', '')` A typical way to do this would be to make a new list: `[s.replace(',', '') for s in some_list]`

Comment: There's no need for the `if`. If the string doesn't contain `,`, `replace()` will just return it unchanged.

Comment: try this : `doses_beta = [ item.replace(',', '') for item in doses ]`

Answer (score 0):

To modify the array value in place, you have to re-assign it. The below function illustrates how to do so.

```py
def remove_commas(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if ',' in array[i]:
            array[i] = array[i].replace(',', '')
    return array
```

Testing:

```
print(remove_commas(["0","0","0","0","1","1,799",""]))
```

Output:

```
['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1799', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

replace() does not change the value, that returns the value with the character modified, so you must assign the return value to the element that you want apply the replace.

```
doses = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1,799', '']
for i in range(len(doses)):
    if ',' in doses[i]:
        doses[i] = doses[i].replace(',', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
original_list = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1,799']
resulting_list = [s.replace(',', '') for s in original_list]

print(original_list)
print(resulting_list)
```

Output:
['0', '0', '0', '0', '1,799'] and
['0', '0', '0', '0', '1799']